# How to change DJango default admin login page

Tags: python, html, django

a beginner here in Django programming. followed several tutorials and kinda thinking how do i change the default admin page of Django? this is where the user will type http://something/admin, then it direct you to a default admin page by Django.

I would like to make my own admin page.
Is this an html file Django is using? if so, where can i find it so i can modify it. or where do i start? i browsed several topics here but answers are kinda vague and no beginner friendly.

I hope someone could help me on this.

Some snippets of my working codes(basic & default):

```
**from urls.py:**
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('website.urls')),
]

**from setting.py:**
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'website',
]
```

when i hit https://localhost/admin, it takes me to this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUH4u.png)

Comment: The admin application consist of many components (Puthon code, templates, CSS, Javascript, per model configuration, ...). What do you want to change exactly?

Comment: You can override the login template of admin page.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates

Answer (score 0):

The default admin page is very important , it can help you manage your website , database .. etc
But it can be change

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

you can change "admin.site.urls" to what you want(a python function)